# PCIe Data clocked refclk question

Tags: clock, data, pcie

When only one clock is used in PCIe and let's assume the clock is connected to device A. 
How does device B transfer data to device A. Device B does not have a clock source.

Comment: Clock recovery, see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/170432/how-pcie-can-tranmit-data-at-2-5-gtps?rq=1

Comment: In PCIe, both devices share a common reference clock...

Answer (score 3):

In the case of PCIe, there is a 100MHz reference clock distributed to *every* device, including the Root node (generally on the CPU).

Because every root, switch, and endpoint share the same reference clock, they can use PLLs to multiply the frequency up to the required clock rate (1.25GHz for Gen 1, 2.5GHz for Gen 2, and 4GHz for Gen 3).

Each device will also contain transceiver logic which deserialises the incoming data, using some form of phase alignment which will account for any small differences in phase of each data line relative to the clock and each other. There is then word alignment which ensures that the correct bit is in the correct place in the recovered parallel data stream.

Comment: "In the case of PCIe, there is a 100MHz reference clock distributed to every device, including the Root node (generally on the CPU)." Not really. There are different clocking architectures - Common clock, Data clocked, Separate clocks. See Fig2 in the following app note or any PCIe clock app note. http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND9202-D.PDF  In data clocked systems how does Device B transmit to device A?

Comment: @hithesh interesting, I hadn't come across that. It seems that in some more niche applications that you can use two different clocks as long as they are approximately the same (within I think it said 300ppm). Will have to read up some more, never come across that before.

Answer (score 1):

High speed serial protocols such as PCIe, SATA, 10G ethernet, USB 3, etc. all use similar methods to communicate without necessarily having shared clock sources.  The technique involves line codes on the transmit side to embed timing information along with the transmitted data, making it easier for the receiver to recover the data successfully.  Naturally, both ends will require reference clocks of some sort, but the receivers are designed to deal with some amount of frequency offset between the two clocks.  Generally this compensation is carried out with a phased locked loop and VCO or a delay locked loop.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_recovery and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_code for more details on how this works.